# Do not show refit menu on boot (only with option key)

Tags: macos, efi

Is it possible to configure rEFIt so that the menu does not automatically show on my macbook when booting? I would like it to boot straight to OSX and only show the menu when I hold the option key, similar to how it worked before I installed rEFIt.

I am using:
MBP 10.6.8, rEFIt 0.14

Comment: Also, check out rEFInd, the 'new' rEFIt http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: Thanks David, I had tried an installation of Mint Debian on my macbook with rEFInd first but it wasn't working so I switched to rEFIt and managed to get it to work. I just now installed rEFInd again and the linux partition boots just fine, so I'm guessing it wasn't rEFInd at all. However, when I press F2 on rEFInd, I no longer get the list of boot options I got before. Does this mean I have to completely uninstall rEFIt? As it stands, I can change between the two.

Comment: By the way, did the first part of your comment get cut off? I can't tell if you wanted to tell me something else before recommending rEFInd.

Comment: Try selecting your OS X partition in System Preferences -> Startup Disk. This should remove the "blessing" from rEFIt.

Comment: That will prevent rEFIt from showing up, effectively uninstalling it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the smallest timeout possible (1 sec) would be a kind of solution, although not exactly what you wanted.

If you have another OS installed on the internal HDD that can be booted by the stock Mac bootloader, you could install refit to the corresponding partition and bless the OS X partition. Thus, when you need refit/ind, you hold the alt key during boot and select the partition where it's installed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences => Startup Disk and then select the disk you want to boot on.

It'll start on this disk every time, if you want to load refit, then press <kbd>alt</kbd> and refit will appears